# SQL Server equivalent of TO_CHAR('STH', '00000')

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to know how I can convert the following Oracle SQL code into SQL Server:

```
TO_CHAR(NUM_COL, '00000')
```

is

```
CAST(('00000'+ NUM_COL) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

correct?

Expected Output:
    `if NUM_COL = 1 => 00001`
    `if NUM_COL = 24 => 00024`
    `if NUM_COL = 383 => 00383`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? use of `TO_CHAR('STH', '00000')` is incorrect. You want to spell a number, or it's  something else you are after?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov please check my last edit, NUM_COL is a numeric field, so it prefixes it with zeroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to preceed value with 0 then I guess following solves your requirement:(PS=> 5 because I wanted result in exact 5 values, if you want different than change tha value)

```
   SELECT RIGHT('00000'+convert(varchar,NUM_COL),5)
```